# mysqli data INSERT not working but no errors

Tags: php, mysqli

mysqli data INSERT not working but there are no errors
i just started with mysqli and i dont really know everything good
i also saw the other questions about it but none of the solutions works for me

this is the form:

```
<head>
<title>NEW</title>
</head>

<body>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">NEW</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <form method="post" action="add.php">
        <tr>
          <td>name</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="name" size="20">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>type</td>
          <td><select name="ptype">
  <option value="a1">a1</option>
  <option value="a2">a2</option>
  <option value="a3">a3</option>
</select>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td align="right"><input type="submit" 
          name="submit" value="GO"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the add.php file:

```
<?php
require("dbconnect.php");
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");


$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `business` (`ptype`, `name`) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $ptype, $name);

$name = $_POST["name"];
$ptype = $_POST["ptype"];



printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);

/* close statement and connection */
$stmt->close();

/* close connection */
}
$db->close();
?>
```

and it says that 0 row inserted

- the dbconnect.php file contains the connection to mysqli

Comment: I can't see where you're running your insert. You prepare it, but don't actually execute it....

Comment: Seeing the 'ss' in your `bind_param` call clued me in to my own problem, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $ptype, $name);

$name = $_POST["name"];
$ptype = $_POST["ptype"];
```

to

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$ptype = $_POST["ptype"];

$stmt->bind_param('ss', $ptype, $name);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have prepared your statement and bound your parameter. Now execute it.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `business` (`ptype`, `name`) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $ptype, $name);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: @IZikDalal pozs has identified another problem with your code that I did not. You might want to consider using (and accepting) his solution.

Answer (score 1):

As @andrewsi mentioned in his comment, you prepared the insert statement but did not execute it. Thats why it is not working.

Try using  `$stmt->execute();` in your code.

So your query should be like this:

```
<?php
require("dbconnect.php");
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");


$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `business` (`ptype`, `name`) VALUES (?, ?)");

$name = $_POST["name"];
$ptype = $_POST["ptype"];

$stmt->bind_param('ss', $ptype, $name);
$stmt->execute();




printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);

/* close statement and connection */
$stmt->close();

/* close connection */
}
$db->close();
?>
```